# How to create a PathGeometry on a background task

Tags: c#, wpf, path, task

I have a WPF application where I draw a line shape on the screen. I use a PathGeometry for that, which I set in code (C#). It all works fine, but the construction of the Path is relatively expensive and it is giving me some problems with my UI. Therefore I tried to create the path in a background task but that proves not to be possible. The PathGeometry class has a DependencyProperty member and it looks like that can only be run on the UI thread.
Is it possible to do the calculation of the Path on a background task?

I am trying something like this on an event handler

```
    ...
    MyPath = await Task<PathGeometry>.Run( () => GeneratePath());
    ...
```

Here `MyPath` is a property in my class that is data-bound to my UI. When I run the code I get an exception `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject`. At first, I thought that somehow the setting of the MyPath was not happening on the UI thread, but then I found that the returned PathGeometry contained the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PathGeometry` is derived from `Freezable` and hence supports cross-thread access after it is frozen.

You can freeze it like this:

```
MyPath = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    var path = GeneratePath();
    path.Freeze();
    return path;
});
```

Or better call Freeze in the GeneratePath method:

```
private PathGeometry GeneratePath()
{
    var path = new PathGeometry();
    ...
    path.Freeze();
    return path;
}

...
MyPath = await Task.Run(() => GeneratePath());
```

Comment: Interesting! I thought the problem was that I used PathGeometry on the thread. This solution proves that there was a problem in using the returned PathGeometry on the UI thread. I tried it out and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The easist way is to change your GeneratePath() method to return a string (the Path's data value) and then use [`Geometry.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to convert it to a UI object once the async method has returned.

Comment: Geometry.Parse would then run on the UI thread and would create a PathGeometry on the UI thread, which is apparently what OP is trying to avoid. However, since Parse may already return a frozen Geometry, you may perhaps also run it in a Task. But why should you then serialize it at all?